# Swapping maximum and minimum values of an array

Tags: arrays

Read in 10 input from the keyboard, and store them in an array. Find the position (or index) of the maximum and minimum values in the array, and swap them (move the biggest element to the position of the smallest, and move the smallest element to the position of the biggest) and print that again. If the user enters 7, 13, -5, 10, 6 then your program should print 7,-5,13,10,6

Here's my code. It would be great if you could make comments on it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] source = new int[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
           source[i] = scn.nextInt();

        int maxIndex = 0;
        int max = source[0];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<10; j++)
            {
               if(source[j]>max)
               {
                  maxIndex = j;
                  max = source[maxIndex];
               }
            }
        }
        int minIndex = 0;
        int min = source[0];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<10; j++)
            {
                if(source[j]<min)
                {
                   minIndex = j;
                   min = source[minIndex];
                }
            }
        }
        int temp = source[minIndex];
        source[minIndex] = source[maxIndex];
        source[maxIndex] = temp;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
           System.out.print(source[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loops are inefficient, and it's not immediately obvious what's happening. I'm assuming this is part of your problem. Another issue is that you instantiate a 10 element array, but may not have 10 elements in the input.

This may better fit the bill.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] source = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           source[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        int maxIndex = 0,
            minIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            int currentValue = source[i];

            if (currentValue > source[maxIndex]) {
                maxIndex = i;
            }

            if (currentValue < source[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }


        int temp = source[maxIndex];
        source[maxIndex] = minValue;
        source[minIndex] = temp;

        for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(source[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the loop inside each of the loops. It's only making you traverse the array too many times.
2. you can merge the min and max loops together. And find both max and min on the same traversal. (this saves basically memory roundtrips).